# What's the best home movie projector?

Tags: video, projector

Given the number of video projectors on the market today, I'm looking for some recommendations.

Here are the features I need:

- 4K-ready
- image quality should be still good during daytime (the room will never be pitch black. It will be mostly used at night though)
- will be projected on white light-filtering roll-down shades (I am aware that this is absolutely not ideal, but I'm looking for minimal setup/gear)
- could be short-throw or mounted to the ceiling (room depth = 12')
- given the room setup, 70" image is enough
- if speakers are built-in that's great, otherwise, I need to be able to connect a wireless home theater system
- price range up to $3,000

So far, I've seen those ones often mentioned:

- Epson Home Cinema LS100 3LCD Ultra Short-throw Projector, Digital Laser Display with Full HD and 100% Color Brightness
- Epson Home Cinema 5040UB 3LCD Home Theater Projector with 4K Enhancement, HDR10, 100% Balanced Color and White Brightness, Ultra Wide DCI-P3 Color Gamut and UltraBlack Contrast
- Optoma UHD50 4K Ultra High Definition Home Theater Projector
- LG HU80KA 4K UHD Laser Smart TV Home Theater CineBeam Projector 2500 Lumens

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**EMOTN H1** uses high quality LED light source with strict quality control and a fully sealed light machine to avoid dust from falling into the screen and producing black spots, which affects the picture quality of the projector; at the same time, it effectively protects the light machine and the life of the light source can reach 50,000 hours.

This sharp 1080P resolution in a portable LCD projector is almost top technological level. The most genuine 250 ANSI Lumens Brightness.Support playback 4K video, 1080P HD video.

[image]

Emotn H1 LCD portable projector button design ideas come from the mechanical keyboard. Each flexible button is composed of an independent shaft switch. Every independent switch will give you an edge, such as a keyboard switch with paragraph sense, the keystroke is consistent and smooth that offers unmistakable feedback when pressed.